# How to use itertools.groupby with a true/false lambda function

Tags: python, group-by

Suppose I have the following string:

```
data = """
Pakistan[country]
Karachi
lahore
islamabad
UAE[country]
dubai
sharjah
India[country]
goa
chennai
"""
```

How to use `itertools.groupby` here to have a dict (with the countries as keys) and their corresponding cities? The closest I have come to is

```
from itertools import groupby

filtered = (line for line in data.split("\n") if line)
for key, values in groupby(filtered, lambda line: line.endswith('[country]')):
    print(key)
    print(list(values))
```

However, how to group the result properly? I am not interested in other possible solutions (I have written a generator function myself) but want to explicitly use/understand `itertools.groupby`.

---

My generator function looks like

```
def grouper(string):
    collect, country, cities = False, None, list()

    filtered = (line for line in string.split("\n") if line)
    for line in filtered:
        if line.endswith('[country]') and not collect:
            country = line.replace("[country]", "")
            collect = True
        elif line.endswith('[country]') and collect:
            yield {country: cities}
            country = line.replace("[country]", "")
            cities = list()
        else:
            cities.append(line)

    if cities:
        yield {country: cities}

for dct in grouper(data):
    print(dct)


for dct in grouper(data):
    print(dct)
```

Which yields

```
{'Pakistan': ['Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad']}
{'UAE': ['dubai', 'sharjah']}
{'India': ['goa', 'chennai']}
```

Comment: What is the end result supposed to be?

Comment: Shouldn't `UAE` end up being a key?

Comment: Do you really want a sequence of dictionaries, rather than a single dictionary whose keys are the countryies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby()` will return an alternating sequence of countries and cities. When it returns a country, you save the country. When it returns cities, you add an entry to the dictionary with the saved country.

```
result = {}
for is_country, values in itertools.groupby(filtered, key = lambda line: line.endswith("[country]")):
    if is_country:
        country = next(values)
    else:
        result[country] = list(values)
```

Comment: `values` is a generator, I've changed it to use `next()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the (at least to me) the most comprehensible solution. Just had to replace `[country]` from the string in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think `groupby` is the wrong tool for this. That's because it collects all successive items that have the same result when the key-function is applied to them. However from the problem description it seems more like you want to "split" your list when the function returns true.

---

However if you really want/must do it with `groupby` then there would be (conceptually) two approaches:

One possible way would be to collect pairs from the `groupby` result. So you collect the one which gave true and the following ones that returned False:

```py
>>> filtered = (line for line in data.split("\n") if line)
>>> l = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(filtered, lambda line: line.endswith('[country]'))]
>>> d = {l[i*2][0].split('[')[0]: l[i*2+1] for i in range(len(l) // 2)}
>>> d
{'Pakistan': ['Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'],
 'UAE': ['dubai', 'sharjah'],
 'India': ['goa', 'chennai']}
```

Or some sort of stateful container as function which remembers what the "current country" is:

```py
class KeepCountry:
    def __call__(self, item):
        if item.endswith('[country]'):
            self._last = item.split('[country]')[0]
        return self._last

>>> filtered = (line for line in data.split("\n") if line)
>>> {k: list(g)[1:] for k, g in groupby(filtered, KeepCountry())}
{'Pakistan': ['Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'],
 'UAE': ['dubai', 'sharjah'],
 'India': ['goa', 'chennai']}
```

Both solutions assume quite a few things - just in case you want to use any of these:

- the first encountered item will be a country
- each country has at least one associated city
- no country name is encountered more than once

---

Just in case a third-party package might be acceptable then you could use [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities) (my library) which provides a [`split`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/split.html)-function for iterables:

```py
>>> from iteration_utilities import Iterable

>>> (Iterable(data.split('\n'))
...    .filter(bool)  # Removes empty lines
...    # Split by countries while keeping them
...    .split(lambda l: l.endswith('[country]'), keep_after=True)[1:]  
...    # Convert to a tuple containing the country as first and the cities as second element
...    .map(lambda l: (l[0][:-9], l[1:]))  
...    .as_dict())
{'Pakistan': ['Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'],
 'UAE': ['dubai', 'sharjah'],
 'India': ['goa', 'chennai']}
```

Comment: Both ugly & slick at the same time -- bravo!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about itertools but why not:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = """
Pakistan[country]
Karachi
lahore
islamabad
UAE[country]
dubai
sharjah
India[country]
goa
chennai
"""

dct = defaultdict(list)

country = ''

for x in data.split('\n')[1:-1]:
    if '[country]' in x:
        country = x.replace('[country]', '')
    else:
        dct[country].append(x)

print(dct)

# {'Pakistan': ['Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'], 'UAE': ['dubai', 'sharjah'], 'India': ['goa', 'chennai']}
```